# Как в Serilog задать связку из нескольких уровней логирования и источников записей?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте для своих WPF проектов всегда использовал `Nlog`, появились проекты на AspNetCore под Linux, я решил попробовать заменить стандартный логер на Serilog (т.к. просматривая код разных проектов для `AspNetCore`, на `GitHub`, практически все используют `Serilog`).

Изучив документацию и примеры, я создал тестовый проект, где добился, того что создается экземпляр логера и интегрируется в контейнер `DI Autofac` через расширение для Autofac.
Т.е. теперь я могу резолвить `ILog`, где мне нужно и получать экземпляр логера `serilog`.

У меня есть требования как нужно настроить логер:

1. MinimumLevel = Info, пишем в Main.log  (основной рабочий лог)
2. Level = Debug, пишем в debug.json      (лог отладки пишется в json(т.к. возможно сохранение состояния объектов) только отдадочную инфу с уровнем Debug)
3. Специализированный лог для отчетности, пишется в report.csv  (Excel для отчетности)

   Логер настраивается примерно так:

   ```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .MinimumLevel.Debug()
       .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
       .WriteTo.Console()
       .WriteTo.File("log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
       .CreateLogger();
   ```

**один MinimumLevel соответствует многим источникам WriteTo И ВСЕ!!!**

Т.е. один экземпляр логера сможет решить только одну задачу из 3-ех?
И как задать Level, а не MinimumLevel?

Т.е. для каждой моей задачи я делаю через билдер `LoggerConfiguration` свой экземпляр ILogger и инжектирую его в нужные сервисы?

Для задачи №3, я думаю, логично создать свой экземпляр логера для каждого сервиса, в который нужна какая-то статистика, но хотелось бы объединить задачи №1 и №2 и легко через Autofac передавать этот экземпляр логера по всей системе.

Используя Nlog я мог решить все задачи в одном экземпляре логера.

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#overriding-per-sink -- а это не то, что вы хотите? По описанию - очень похоже.

Comment: restrictedToMinimumLevel переопределяет минимальный уровень для WriteTo.  Но как мне сделать, чтобы ТОЛЬКО DebugLevel писался в файл "Debug.log"?

Comment: Хм, вот это без понятия. Ни разу не было даже такой необходимости, потому что потом в этом логе записей же не хватает, что происходило.

Comment: Для того чтобы контролировать работу приложения есть основной лог с MinLevel = Information. Отладку туда писать не нужно. Но и в специфический лог отладки лишняя инфа мне не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для записи во множество файлов используются **sub-loggers**, см. [Serilog 2.0 adventures with sub-loggers](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/). При этом сообщения можно фильтровать через `Filter`

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File("Main.log")
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(le => le.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
        .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), "debug.json"))
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .WriteTo.File(new MyCsvFormatter(), "report.csv"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

Также [Serilog : Log to different files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38491795/1133809)

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо,то что нужно.